# How to make detail view scrollable in master detail app

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch, uiscrollview

I have only been working in iOS for a few months but I have been banging my head against the wall for hours and hours for something that seems like it should be pretty straightforward. I used the master detail template in Xcode for an iPad app.  I want the detail portion to be scrollable to show content below what is visible in the frame, in either orientation.  I have tried numerous combinations of adding scrollviews in the DetailViewController in viewWillAppear, viewDidLoad, loadView...and the best I can come up with is what looks like a scrollable view on the top layer as it does show scroll bars and shows me that I did the scrollView.contentSize correctly as I can pan around, but the actual view with the fields and stuff doesn't move and the fields are unable to be edited.  Here is my viewDidAppear as it stands at the moment.  As you can see in the NSLogs I am trying to understand the view stack.  If I uncomment the line before the logs, I lose the scroll bars altogether.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

    UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 768, 1024)];
    scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(2048, 2048);

    UIView *parentView = [[UIView alloc] init];

    parentView = [[self view] superview];

    [[parentView superview] addSubview:scrollView];

    //[scrollView addSubview:[self view]];

    NSLog(@"%@", [parentView superview]);
    NSLog(@"%@", parentView);
    NSLog(@"%@", [super view]);
    NSLog(@"%@", [self view]);

    [scrollView setDelegate:self];

}
```

I would sincerely appreciate any guidance or tips on how to properly implement UIScrollView for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

You should add the `UIScrollView` in IB. Be sure to move all of your existing views and controls to be subviews of the scroll view. And you'll have to link the scroll view to an `IBOutlet` so you can set the content size in your view controller.

Comment: Easy enough.  I guess I was making it too difficult by trying to program it instead of using IB.  One "side effect" I have now is that my view was actually a UIControl so that when I touched outside of any UITextField it would dismiss the keyboard.  Seems like I can't have both that and a UIScrollView co-exist?

Comment: You can subclass `UIScrollView` and override `touchesEnded` to detect touches in the view.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to wrap a uiscrollview around your main view's superview (which you have incorrectly tried to take ownership of (it should be NULL anyways)), why not herd your UI elements into a full-sized subview and wrap the scrollview around that?  It would be much much easier.

Your hierarchy would look like this:

Self.view -> ScrollView (with contentSize set) -> UIView containing elements that need to be scrolled -> various UI elements